# How to delete a git branch named "--track"

Tags: git, branch, git-track

I made a mistake when I checked out a new branch with git. `git version 1.7.1`

I ran `git branch -b --track origin/develop` and I got a branch named `--track`. How can I delete it?

What I have done:

```
$ git branch
--track
* develop
master

$ git branch -d --track
$ git branch -d "--track"
$ git branch -D --track
$ git branch -D "--track"
$ git branch -D '--track'
$ git branch
--track
* develop
master
```

Comment: What version of Git are you running?  I see trying to run this as a fatal error.

Comment: @Makoto yeah, I wasn't able to create such a thing either, except the hard way :)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than trying to figure out (if there is) a way to get the git tools to do it, you can simply

```
rm .git/refs/heads/--track
```

Comment: It's easy to forget that branches are just files with refs in them.

Answer (score 4):

The method in [hobbs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47785305/1256452) will likely work.  If that fails, you can use `git update-ref` to delete the branch name in a way that will also not start with `-`:

```
git update-ref -d refs/heads/--track
```

This should work even if the branch has gotten packed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git branch -D -- --track
```

`--` separates options from arguments.